How to customize tmux pane separator
I'm customizing my tmux setup to match Neovim's appearance, specifically the vertical pane separator used in vsplits (|).
In Neovim, I use this configuration for the separator:
vim.opt.fillchars = {
    vert = "|",  -- Simple vertical line
}

In tmux, I have tried setting pane border styles like this:
set -g pane-border-style 'fg=#232629,bg=default'
set -g pane-active-border-style 'fg=magenta,bg=default'

However, tmux still uses a continuous line as the separator, not a simple | like in Neovim.
How can I customize tmux to show a separator that matches Neovim's vsplit (|), without the continuous line?
What I tried:

I adjusted the pane-border-style and pane-active-border-style settings to customize the separator.
I attempted to use different separator characters (e.g., │), but tmux still shows a continuous line instead of a simple |.

What I experienced:

The separator in tmux still appears as a continuous line rather than the simple | separator like in Neovim.

here is tmux separator

here my nvim separator


i solved that by:
set -g pane-border-lines simple
